# Extract field output components from abaqus odb file using python script in a user defined cordinate system

Tags: scripting, coordinate-transformation, abaqus-odb

I have generated odb file of cylindrical structure analysis in abaqus. Extraction of sigma11 (stress in global X) field output at all elements has been done using a python script. But for better interpretation of results I would like to get the radial stress component in a cylindrical cordinate system. The cordinate system is made and saved. What is the syntax for specifying the cylindrical csys.

But for better interpretation of results I would like to get the radial stress component in a cylindrical cordinate system. The cordinate system is made and saved. What is the syntax for specifying the cylindrical csys.